# Passing dynamic initial value to riverpod provider without a need to use it as a family provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a usecase as follow: a screen with initial filter object, this screen is used multiple times with different filter configuration, what I need to achieve is to pass an initial different filter object for each instance from this screen to notifier provider then I can change the state of this filter using the provider, I have done that using the provided code sample below but I'm wondering if I can achieve this without making the notifier scoped like that, also if don't need the provider outside the filter screen, is this a good way to do that?

Here is a full minimal code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class Filter {
  final String? foo;
  final String? bar;

  const Filter({
    this.foo,
    this.bar,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other is Filter && foo == other.foo && bar == other.bar;

  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(foo, bar);
}

class FilterNotifier extends AutoDisposeNotifier<Filter> {
  final Filter filter;

  FilterNotifier(this.filter);
  @override
  Filter build() {
    return filter;
  }

  void update(Filter filter) {
    state = filter;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            const filter = Filter(foo: 'foo');
            if (filter.foo != null) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const ScreenDependsOnFilter(
                    filter: Filter(foo: 'foo'),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const ScreenDependsOnFilter(
                    filter: Filter(bar: 'bar'),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          child: const Text('Go to filter screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenDependsOnFilter extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ScreenDependsOnFilter({super.key, required this.filter});
  final Filter filter;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ScreenDependsOnFilter> createState() =>
      _ScreenOneDependsOnFilterState();
}

class _ScreenOneDependsOnFilterState
    extends ConsumerState<ScreenDependsOnFilter> {
  late final filterNotifierProvider =
      NotifierProvider.autoDispose<FilterNotifier, Filter>(
    () => FilterNotifier(widget.filter),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.listen(
      filterNotifierProvider,
      (prev, current) {
        if (prev != current) {
          // Do some staff
        }
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Filter Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could always just use an InheritedWidget. Seems perfect here

Comment: @GregoryConrad May you explain more about that? how this is related to riverpod?

Comment: If you need to scope some state to a particular subset of the widget tree, your options are to use scoped containers via riverpod or use a good old InheritedWidget. Scoping containers is a bit more of an advanced topic and not often a great idea, and you can always just use an InheritedWidget